# Submit form with AngularJS frontend to Express API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm a complete beginner with Express and Angular and over the last day or two I've been trying to build a simple blog app.

So far the API includes getting all posts, submitting a post, and getting, updating, deleting a post by ID.

The API is functional as far as my tests in Postman are concerned. Everything works as it should. I can get all posts and display them on a page using an ng-repeat.

I'm trying to figure out how to submit something -- I've had no luck and all the examples online and various tutorials have been confusing me by being sufficiently different both from my current thinking and from eachother to the point where I thought I'd ask here.

Here's my code -- forgive how sloppy it is. By this point it has been hacked to pieces.

```
angular.module('blogApp',[])

.controller('PostController', function($scope,$http){
    $scope.formData = {

        title: '',
        body: ''

    };

        $http.get('/api/blog')
            .success(function(data){

                $scope.posts = data;


            });

    $scope.createPost = function (){

            $http({method: 'POST', url:'/api/blog', data: 'formData'})

        }

        function editPost(){}

        function deletePost(){}

});
```

and the submit form on the view looks something like this

```
     <form ng-submit="createPost()">
      Title<br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="{{formData.title}}" name="title">
      <br>
      Body<br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="{{formData.body}}" name="body">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I will worry about proper validations etc. later, but for now I'll be happy if when I click 'submit' something actually gets posted! I've made sure ng-app is in the main html tag and my controller has scope over everything in the body.

Hopefully this is enough information for anyone interested to go on. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: add ng-controller='PostController' to the form and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you put something inside the ng-model, you put the expression directly without the curly brackets, your post function is not finding the data when they are inside the brackets.

```
<form ng-submit="createPost()">
  Title<br>
  <input type="text" ng-model="formData.title" name="title">
  <br>
  Body<br>
  <input type="text" ng-model="formData.body" name="body">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

also it appears that you are passing the data into the post request as a string, where it actually inside the $scope, so you should pass $scope.postData instead of 'postData'
also it will be good if you modify your post request to resolve the promise so you can know what happenned after you posted using .then to resolve the promise or observe the error.

```
 $http({method: 'POST', url:'/api/blog', data: $scope.formData})
    .then(function(response){
         //your code in case the post succeeds
         console.log(response);
     })
    .catch(function(err){
         //your code in case your post fails
         console.log(err);
     });
```

Comment: That has got it working -- thank you so much for taking the time to answer me. I'm slowly starting to understand some of the concepts of Node etc -- it certainly doesn't seem entirely intuitive. 

Am I right in saying that the .then can be used to show 'post successful' type messages to the user?

I'm going to have a proper look over my code tomorrow to make sure I understand everything so far. Thanks again!

Comment: You are Welcome! to simplify things, when you do $http.post to a server, you have to wait till the response come back to see if the post was successful or not, .then is a way to catch the response once it arrives back from server (callback afer response comes back from server), and .catch() will trigger callback in case something went wrong. please take a look [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for more understanding of how $http works. If you think I answered your question, please mark it as the right answer. Thanks.